Create copy of sheet and get URL of new sheet in a cell or the original
I need to generate a new service sheet when a customer brings in their vehicle.
This script below works where Row 1 is filled with the customers details. The script is on a minute timer so L3 shows if new details have been received in A1 and across the row. A1 is then deleted so L3 now indicates there is no new data so the script does not run again. I would like to get the URL of the newly created sheet in L3 of the original sheet.
function createCopy() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.getRange('F3').activate();
spreadsheet.getRange('N2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(),            SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
var myValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("G4").getValue();
var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxx");
DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()).makeCopy(myValue,destinationFolder);
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('ServiceSheet'), true);
spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});

Not sure how to accomplish getting the URL into L3
Can anyone help please? Thanks

Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is usually not a good idea to create a new spreadsheet file for every customers. Insert additional tabs in the master spreadsheet instead. It only takes two clicks to duplicate the current tab.

Note that the trigger you created is only active in the spreadsheet where you set it up. The script creates copies of the spreadsheet, and the copies will not have the trigger automatically.

Use File.getUrl(), like this:
function createCopy() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const flagCell = ss.getRange('ServiceSheet!A1');
  if (flagCell.isBlank()) return;
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('...put folder ID here...');
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange('F3').setValue(sheet.getRange('N2').getValue());
  const myValue = sheet.getRange('G4').getValue();
  const newFile = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).makeCopy(myValue, destinationFolder,);
  sheet.getRange('L3').setValue(newFile.getUrl());
  flagCell.clearContent();
}

See File.getUrl().

That works a treat doubleunary. Many Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Hi doubleunary. I have sent the contents of L3 to another sheet, (Cell A3) I need to then copy that contents to whichever cell contains the text "SheetURL" Can you help please? Thanks

Please ask only one question per post. Post a new question instead.
